# How to show $3$-period point means positive entropy

Tags: dynamical-systems, entropy, ergodic-theory

Let $f$ be a continuous function from $ [0,1] $ to itself with a $3$-period point. How to show that the topology entropy of $f$ is positive?

Comment: Nice question. What did you try?

Comment: I tried to find a semiconjugacy from this dynamic to a Bernoulli shift, but failed to construct

Comment: Hi! How  do you define the topological entropy and what tells you your statement is correct?

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by a little improvement of a proof by T.y.Li and J.Yorke showing that "3-peirod implies chaos". Use Markov graph and the concept "$f$-cover" to find a semiconjugate to sybolic system with positive entropy.I find the related theory in Brin and Stuck's book *Introduction to Dynamic systems Chapter7.3*